# Write to standard input when svn is asking for password - c# process

Tags: c#, svn

I am trying to create an app that uses the Subversion command-line. I can pass through the username with the following:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Program.UserName);
```

And after that it asks for the password: `Password for 'xy':`. But with `WriteLine` it doesn't work. No characters appear:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Program.Password);
```

`Program.Password` contains the correct password.

Code snippet:

```
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{                    
  FileName = c.CommandName,
  Arguments = c.CommandArgs,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardInput = true
};

process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Program.UserName);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Program.Password);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a svn library, for example:
http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

For a Walkthrough how to get started take a look at:
http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm

Comment: I dont find any solution for this problem, so i'm using SharpSvn. It's really the easiest way.